# Detect browser support of html file input element

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way with a javascript/jquery/crazy-css-hack to detect if the user's browser supports rendering a functional `<input type="file" />` file upload element?  For example, the safari browser on iOS won't render the element and I would like to instead show a message to the user that the functionality isn't supported.  I know I can inspect the user agent and check to see if it an iphone/ipad/etc but I don't know what other browsers do or do not support it or will or will not support it in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Galambalazs' answer pointed me in the right direction for iOS only.  I ended up using this:

```
function supportsFileInput() {
  var dummy = document.createElement("input");
  dummy.setAttribute("type", "file");
  return dummy.disabled === false;
}
```

However, it doesn't work for most Android devices, as this function always returns true but renders the button with the text "Uploads disabled".

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to do *dummy test*:

```
function supportInputType(type) {
  var dummy = document.createElement("input");
  dummy.setAttribute("type", type);
  return dummy.type !== "text";
}
```

Better yet if you want to execute only once:

```
var SUPPORT_INPUT_FILE = supportInputType("file");
```

Then you can use this *"constant"* in all your code.

The way the test works: First it creates a dummy element. It will have the default `type = "text"`. Next you try to set it to `file`. In case the browser doesn't support this type it will remain `text`.

Have fun!

Comment: This is a good idea but testing on the iPhone returns true even though it doesn't in fact support rendering a file input.

Answer (score 1):

iOS renders the file input element as "disabled". So you can test if there is a disabled input field. I used jQuery to do so.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(this).find('[type=file]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('disabled')) {
        // do sth.
        }    
    })
});
```